# Regex remove last folder from path

Tags: regex

Using Regex I need to remove the last folder from a path:

```
Example : C:\Temp\Dir1\

Output : C:\Temp\
```

Please don't suggest that I can do this with c# or other programming language.  I really do need the regex for this.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Still you need to know the regex engine. Is it regex executed in javascript / c# / anything else?

Comment: Maras, for something this simple? Not really.

Comment: sorry Maras i didnt understand your comment?

Comment: as for what i tried, many many things online that say they do what i need but dont work. Too many to comment on and i dont understand them anyway :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace

```
[^\\]+\\?$
```

by nothing. This works for paths like `C:\Temp\Dir1` (no trailing backslash) as well. It fails  for the root directory of a drive.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I really find regex so difficult to get my head around.   This works a treat :)

Comment: i am displaying all the folders from the root folder using recursion... your replace works but it is not replacing the slash. for example a path is c:\wind\sam\dam . the regex did not replace /dam yet it replaced dam. then i use another statememt to remove the trailing slash because i do not know how your regex works and i just copied and pasted... i used [^\/\+\/?$ cause i have to move to linux system... what should i do

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Thought it might be polite to mention I got to incorporate it into an answer on another site, here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245057/how-to-automate-writer-output-directory-and-filename-in-fme-desktop/245074#245074 (not sure if there's any other way to give cross-site credit)

Comment: @Mark: Well, I doubt this answer here reaches any threshold of originality, as it's fairly obvious, but thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is working with groups:

```
\w\:(\\\w+)*(\\\w+\\)
```

Replace the second group with empty string.

[Demo](http://regexr.com?31d6c)

But, I admit, Joey solution is much more... slim!

Answer (score 0):

for mac file path `oldPath.replace(/[^\/]+\/?$/,'')`

Answer (score 0):

In java this is how it worked for me:

```
String filepath = "C:\Temp\Dir1\"   
filePath = filePath.replaceAll("[^\\\\]+$", "");
```

Output: C:\Temp\

For removing trailing backslash did the following:

```
String filepath = "C:\Temp\Dir1\"   
filePath = filePath.replaceAll("[^\\\\]+$", "").replaceAll("[\\\\]?$", "");
```

Output: C:\Temp

Answer (score 0):

[^\\\/]+[\\\/]?$
The above will match the last directory for both forward slash and back slash'ed paths:

Windows Style:
C:\Users\**vscheidegger**
C:\Users\**vscheidegger\**

Linux Style:
/mnt/media/**vscheidegger**
/mnt/media/**vscheidegger/**